# Google assistant custom commands

Tags: google-assistant

Is there anyway I can have custom commands for google assistant, which will show results how I want it to be?

Comment: Have a look at this [site](http://ok-google.io)

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) now supports Google Assistant. You can create your own commands that interact with any of the IFTTT connected platforms. For an instance you can have a digest where you give notes to GOogle, and at a custom time every day you get those notes sent to you on email. [Direct link to Google Assistant account with a lot of applets](https://ifttt.com/google_assistant)

As IFTTT interacts with all kinds of platforms, you have a large world of opportunities when it comes to creating your own commands. There are a lot of pre-made applets, including things like turning off lights, there is even one where you say "good morning" to the assistant, and it turns on a coffee machine

Comment: I really appreciate you adding the second list.  Sites that hype themselves while trying to get you to "try" them while providing no documentation or materials to evaluate *before* you try them really *grind my gears*.